# How do I render a list of items into my React Component from mlab?

Tags: reactjs, mlab

I'm trying to render the items inside of {this.state.courses.name} but nothing is showing up. I'm not even getting anything in the terminal for the console.log inside ComponentDidMount(). Is it simply a case that the code is never reaching ComponentDidMount()? I am new to React so it may be a simple mistake...

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import CourseList from '../CourseList/CourseList.js';
import axios from 'axios';
//import router from '../server/controllers/course.controller.js'
const cookies = new Cookies();

class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      courses: {},
    };
    console.log(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("localhost:3001/courses")
    .then(function(response) {
      this.setState({
        courses: response.data.courses
      })
      console.log('I am getting the response from axios courses here!',response.data)
    })
  }
  render() {
    let inst = cookies.get('instructor');
    console.log('ins', inst);
    inst = inst.fullName;
    //CourseController.getAllCourses((req,res) => {
    //console.log(res.data)
    //})
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="greeting"> Welcome Back, {this.props.fullName}</div>
        <div className="addCourseLink">
          <Link to="/addCourse">Add a new course </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="dashboard-your-courses"><h2>Your Courses</h2></div>
        <div className="courseList">{this.state.courses.name}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    fullName: state.auth.fullName
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(DashboardPage);
```

Comment: Do you get something like `setState is not a function` in the console?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors. I wish I could get response.data to show up so I have a definite idea of what the response object looks like.

Comment: Try using https://www.getpostman.com to do a GET on `localhost:3001/courses` and see if you actually have some data.

Comment: Try using an arrow function in your axios' then. I guess `this` is `undefined` inside that function right now. Can you console.log `this` there? Also, try moving the response `console.log` above `setState`.

Comment: Kevin, I am getting data back on the Postman installed on my computer. It looks like {
  "courses": [
    {
      "_id": "5949328eafbad560ecdfba5e",
      "name": "Math 300",
      "_creator": "59360ff893dfcb1a24e0e855",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "59493590afbad560ecdfba5f",
      "name": "Math 300",
      "_creator": "59360ff893dfcb1a24e0e855",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5949374fafbad560ecdfba60",
      "name": "English 300",
      "_creator": "59360ff893dfcb1a24e0e855",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @squgeim I tried something like this but not getting anything back. I think that may be the issue that this is undefined. I feel dumb for asking but how do I instantiate this? componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("localhost:3001/courses")
    .then(response => {
      console.log('I am getting the response from axios courses here!',response.data)
      console.log(this)
      this.setState({
        courses: response.data
      })
    })
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the object below is the result of calling GET on localhost:3000/courses

```
{
     "courses": [{
         "_id": "5949328eafbad560ecdfba5e",
         "name": "Math 300",
         "_creator": "59360ff893dfcb1a24e0e855",
         "__v": 0
     }, {
         "_id": "59493590afbad560ecdfba5f",
         "name": "Math 300",
         "_creator": "59360ff893dfcb1a24e0e855",
         "__v": 0
     }, {
         "_id": "5949374fafbad560ecdfba60",
         "name": "English 300",
         "_creator": "59360ff893dfcb1a24e0e855",
         "__v": 0
     }]
 }
```

You have to make sure that you are mapping the state courses correctly with the value of courses property in the above object, which is an array. You might want to initialise courses with an array instead. Also, since courses is an array, you probably want to use map as well. In the code below, I have created a component to render the courses.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import CourseList from '../CourseList/CourseList.js';
import axios from 'axios';
//import router from '../server/controllers/course.controller.js'
const cookies = new Cookies();

class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      courses: [],
    };
    console.log(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("localhost:3001/courses")
    .then(function(response) {
      this.setState({
        // given that response.data.courses is an object with a couse property
        courses: response.data.courses.courses
      })
      console.log('I am getting the response from axios courses here!',response.data)
    })
  }
  render() {
    let inst = cookies.get('instructor');
    console.log('ins', inst);
    inst = inst.fullName;
    //CourseController.getAllCourses((req,res) => {
    //console.log(res.data)
    //})
    
    // render your functional component here
    return <DashboardContent courses={this.state.courses} fullName={this.props.fullName} />
  }
}

// new functional component
function DashboardContent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        props.courses.map(course => {
          return <div>
            <div className="greeting"> Welcome Back, {props.fullName}</div>
            <div className="addCourseLink">
              <Link to="/addCourse">Add a new course </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="dashboard-your-courses"><h2>Your Courses</h2></div>
            <div className="courseList">{course.name}</div>
          </div>   
        }) 
      }
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    fullName: state.auth.fullName
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(DashboardPage);
```